# Git command is not returning any value in makefile

Tags: linux, bash, git, shell, makefile

I have a simple makefile that should print the Git log, which looks as below.

```
SHELL=/bin/bash

get_log:
    echo $(git log)
```

However, when I run `make get_log` nothing is returned. Although if I run `git log` directly in the CMD, I get results.

What might be the issue here?

<sub>Note: The make file is formatted correctly; I am using spaces instead of ***tabs*** to post the question here.</sub>

Answer (score 6):

The line

```
 echo $(git log)
```

has two flaws: it uses a single `$` which tells make to look for the contents of the variable `git` but with an erroneous space and `log` as addition. I don't think that `make` would find anything under this ill-formed access which means that it silently replaces the expression with ... nothing. Secondly, you don't need the `echo` as `git log` is writing to [standard output](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_.28stdout.29) anyway. So the correct form would simply be:

```
get_log:
   git log
```

If this is very helpful is another question. I prefer separation of concerns also within scripts—as long as you can't add any benefit like getting the log from the deployment branch or something similar, I would stay away from fiddling with Git. The user has to learn its basics like `log` anyway.

PS: I recommend that you read the manual at *[GNU Make Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/)* as you are lacking even the most basic understanding of `make` (no offense), and it will frustrate you again and again at this point of (lack of) knowledge.